# RNN model can remember the previous text in prediction stage

Tags: python, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I have developed a text classification problem using RNN,keras and python.Here my main challenge is that I am able to classify the text in after fitting the model.When its come to prediction of model,i have a text sentence It's suppose to classify which class its belongs and if same sentence the user had entered to model prediction again ,its suppose to say that you have already entered and got the answer.
Does RNN model can  remembered previous question asked in model prediction .

Please suggest does RNN model able to do  this remembering previous sentence ,if yes suggest me how to go ahead further ,if not why it is not possible?

Comment: Without your code, or an example of its usage, we have very little context to answer your question. Please provide us with more context - as this is written, it is hard to figure out what you need.

Comment: at predictions stage can rnn model remebered the previous  predictions in current  predictions